# Got timeout reading communication packets vs Got error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, timeout

I felt "**Got error reading communication packets**" is related to max_allowed_packet variable and "**Got timeout reading communication packets**" is related 'net_read_timout' parameter or network issues.

Let me know whether my understanding is correct or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For my situation, the master met with the error timeout, but the slave run the same sql successfully. The sql is about load data, so the master actually finished reading the whole packet?

Comment: By which command you are loading data? generally slave cannot run the statement if the same fails in master. How are you sure that slave ran the query successfully? does the slave contain all the records from load data file , if you felt slave executed the command successfully.

Comment: Query caused different errors on master and slave. Error on master: 'Got timeout reading communication packets' (1159), Error on slave: 'no er
ror' (0). Default database: 'jn_asst'. Query: 'load data ....', Error_code: 0